# nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

[image]Using spring and hibernate Im getting the following error and I dont know what Im doing wrong.
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.

the controller

```
package com.springapp.mvc.controller;

import com.springapp.mvc.model.UsersEntity;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    UsersEntity user;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView userLogin() {
        return new ModelAndView("login", "student", user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/home"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView Success(@ModelAttribute("student") UsersEntity user, ModelAndView model) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build());
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        model.setViewName("home");
        model.addObject(user);

        return model;
    }

}
```

the model

```
package com.springapp.mvc.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by JLC on 11/26/14.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "", catalog = "test")
public class UsersEntity {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 30)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 20)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UsersEntity that = (UsersEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (password != null ? !password.equals(that.password) : that.password != null) return false;
        if (username != null ? !username.equals(that.username) : that.username != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

hibernate configuration file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

      <mapping class="com.springapp.mvc.model.UsersEntity"/>

      <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Stack trace

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService;)V
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:247)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:73)
    com.springapp.mvc.controller.HelloController.Success(HelloController.java:30)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:439)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:427)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Have you checked you only have one Hibernate Jar in your classpath ? i.e LIB

Comment: Yes, only one in the classpath

Comment: can you post the actual stack trace, there should be a class after `.<init>`

Comment: just added the stack trace @KennethClark

Comment: This really does look like multiple different versions of hibernate  jar

Comment: How can I check for those versions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65740/discussion-between-javier-lopez-and-kenneth-clark).

Answer (score 0):

May be problem will be in this code.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()); 
//till here its fine
//now your building the sessionfactory without applying builder reference 
SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build()); //here builder.build() should be there which gives ServiceRegistry object.
Session session = factory.openSession();
```

Try this

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
Session session = factory.openSession();
```

Please make sure that you have correct version of Hibernate jar in your classpath. Avoid multiple version of hibernate jars in the classpath.

Comment: R u running spring mvc project using hibernate? If yes make sure all the jars are present in lib folder of WEB-INF